# Pandas assign() has no effect when used in user-defined function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I use the [`DataFrame.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) method in my own function `foobar`, it has no effect to the global `DataFrame`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

def foobar(df):
    # has no affect to the "global" df
    df.assign(Z = lambda x: x.A + x.B)

    return df    
    

data = {'A': range(3),
        'B': range(3)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = foobar(df)
# There is no 'Z' column in this df
print(df)
```

The result output

```
   A  B                                                                                          
0  0  0                                                                                          
1  1  1                                                                                          
2  2  2
```

I assume this has something to do with the difference of *views* and *copy's* in Pandas. But I am not sure how to handle this the right and elegant Pandas-way.

Comment: You need to assign it back i.e., `df = df.assign(Z=lambda x: x.A + x.B)` or it's effectively doing nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) returns a `DataFrame` so you need to assign the result to the same `df`. Try this:

```py
def foobar(df):
    df = df.assign(Z = lambda x: x.A + x.B)

    return df
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It really was a misunderstanding based on assumptions grounded in the object orientation, not a typo.